# What is the sum of the roots of this equation: $\left\lvert \frac {2x-1}{6} \right\rvert + \left\lvert 2-4x \right\rvert = \frac {26}{3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

> What is the sum of the roots of this equation?
>    $$\left\lvert \frac {2x-1}{6} \right\rvert + \left\lvert 2-4x \right\rvert = \frac {26}{3}.$$

I currently don't have any idea about this question.

Comment: Did you see that $|2-4x|=2|2x-1|$?

Comment: Too many absolute value questions....

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\iff26\cdot\dfrac63=|2x-1|+6|(-2)(2x-1)|=|2x-1|(1+6|-2|)=?$$ as $|a|=|-a|$ for any complex number $a$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. The left-hand side is a function in $x$ which is symmetric with respect to $1/2$ (note that $|2-4x|=2|2x-1|$). Therefore the average of the roots is $1/2$.

Comment: I didn't get your hint.

Comment: The function $|x-1/2|$ is symmetric with respect to $1/2$ therefore also the roots of $|x-1/2|=a$ will be symmetric (for any value of $a$).

Comment: is $x = \frac {-41}{12}$ and $\frac {63}{22}$?

Comment: You can find the sum of the roots without finding the roots!

Comment: But how? Can you show it?

Comment: My hint says that, by symmetry, the average of the roots is $1/2$, so their sum is...

Answer (score 1):

it simplifies to
$$\frac{1}{6}|2x-1|+2|2x-1|=\frac{26}{3}$$
and from here we get
$$|2x-1|=4$$
Can you proceed?